# Historical Daf Yomi calendar

Tags: calendar, internet, daf-yomi

Is there a website that allows you to find what Daf was studied on the a particular date as part of the Daf Yomi cycle?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but go here and scroll down and change the date https://dafyomi.co.il/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found that [Daf Yomi Calendar](http://www.dafyomi.org/machzor.php?machzor=13) has the calendar for cycles 11 - 15.
This site does not have any earlier cycles.

I have found [D.A.F.'s Talmud Tools](https://dafyomi.co.il/new_datefinder.php?cycle=1&gid2=1&daf2=2) which allows you to search back by Daf, Hebrew date, or English Date. The first cycle shown is Brachos 2 which started Sep 6, 1923, Thu, 25 Elul 5683 and ended Sep 11, 1923, Tue, 1 Tishrei 5684.

As an example, I was born on 9 Cheshvan 5707 (Sunday November 3, 1946) which was Pesachim daf 27 of the fourth cycle.

Comment: If you change the URL for the Daf Yomi Calendar to something else, it seems to give you that cycle. For example, here is [Cycle 5](http://www.dafyomi.org/machzor.php?machzor=5&masechta=brachos). It seems to just be back-calculating, since you can also put in "-1" and it will give you dates.

Comment: @magicker72 yes it seems to back calculate based on the current number of pages. For example, the Cycle 5 that you point to shows brachos 2 on March 18, 1953. The Talmud Tools calculation shows it on April 14, 1953. Also cycle 1 calculates one daf per day in 1923 starting from July 10, 1923, while the Torah Tools shows that the first cycle had Brachos 2 learned from 25 Elul (Sept 6) thorough Rosh Hashana (Sept 11, 1923). Thus the calendar is not usable before cycle 11. Similarly, my birthday in cycle 4 was Pesachim 27 but resetting the Daf Yomi Calendar to cycle 4 in Pesachim is Sept 28, 1946

Comment: Interesting. The number of pages hasn't changed... is something to do with Shekalim?

Comment: @magicker72 Wikipedia says For the first cycle, there were only 2,702 pages of Talmud on the schedule; later leading Rabbis increased it to 2,711,[18] changing the edition used for Tractate Shekalim, taken from the Jerusalem Talmud, to one with more pages.  Shlomi, B. "The Historic First Siyum HaShas". Hamodia Magazine, 10 May 2012, pp. 12–13.

Answer (score 6):

The [Simple Luach app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/jewish-calendar-simple-luach/id918952058) lists the day's daf in its calendar. Navigate to the calendar tab, and click the icon at the top right. This goes back to September 11, 1923 which lists Berachos 2 as the day's daf. The previous day, September 10, (and all earlier days) lists the day's daf as "null". Here are screenshots showing this:

[image: Screenshot of the calendar entry for 9/11/1923 showing the day's daf]

[image: Screenshot of the calendar entry for 9/10/1923 showing "null" for the day's daf]

Answer (score 3):

TorahCalc recently added an online calculator that does exactly that. You can enter any date and it will tell you the Daf Yomi page and cycle number for that date.

[Torah Calc Daf Yomi Calculator](https://torahcalc.com/daf-yomi)